# Python - Open TXT, Randomize, Save as New File

Tags: python, random, lines

I've been messing around with randomizing in python for awhile now but for some reason I'm stuck here. Maybe it's just too late at night...

Anyway, I'm looking for a quick an easy method in Python to;

- Open TXT File
- Randomize Lines
- Save as new TXT File

I'm feeling kinda dumb here...
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`random.shuffle`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle) to randomize a sequence:

```
import random

with open('filename', 'rb') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()

random.shuffle(lines)

with open('newfilename', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(lines)
```

**Edit:** The method of shuffling suggested in the other answer is wrong. See the comments and the links therein. Here is a more correct example of a shuffle:

```
end = len(lines) - 1
for i in range(end + 1):
    choice = random.randint(i, end)
    lines[i], lines[choice] = lines[choice], lines[i]
```

After this shuffle, assuming perfect randomness from `randint`, the position of a line is *completely uncorrelated* with its position before the shuffle. Using the naive algorithm in the other answer, that isn't the case. The two shuffles both take the same number of operations.

Comment: @TylerCrompton No particular reason, that's my default. It probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Hmm. I need to read up on that anyway. Speaking of personal defaults, I prefer to print to standard out so that I can either see the results in the shell or I can choose to save the output as a file. Maybe it's because that's the way I was taught. :/

Comment: @TylerCrompton "Save as a new file" was part of the question, so I did that. You shouldn't use `print` on Python 2 if you want exactly what you started with -- it adds either a newline or space to the end of the line.